# Heroku website shows Server Error (500) when opened

Tags: python, django, heroku

every time I try to open my website on heroku, it shows the error message
**Server Error (500)**.

All my static files are correctly setup (*I know this because I ran* ***`python3 manage.py collectstatic`***).

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And my debug is set to false

[image]

I forgot to post an image of my logs, this is what it says;

[image]

Comment: ...why would you share part of your `settings.py` as text (good!) and another part as an image ([bad!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577))?

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail, e.g. by running `heroku logs`.

Comment: I guess that an error to correct, thanks.

Comment: And about checking heroku logs I'm on it.